# How to conditional format each row with heat map in excel?

Tags: excel, formatting, format, conditional-statements, heatmap

I am currently trying to apply conditional formatting (using heatmap or up/down arrow icons) to my entire worksheet to show the trend for each row individually.

My rows have various metrics, my column displays time in quarters, and the data is compliance.

Is there a way to apply heat map formatting to the entire worksheet without having to use format painter for each row? Each row is a different metric so it would not make sense to format pain the whole excel sheet as the calibrations will be off.

[image]

Comment: some sample data and desired outcome would be helpful otherwise the answer might not be what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks - I've included a snap shot of my table. Any thoughts?